# How does this circuit with a MOSFET and LED work if the respective diodes are facing opposite directions?

Tags: led, mosfet, diodes

This could be a stupid question, but I don't get how this circuit functions properly, considering that the LED is facing the opposite direction as the body diode within the MOSFET. Is this generally how MOSFETs are supposed to be arranged when driving an LED or something like this?
[image]

Comment: The MOSFET is typically used as a switch, so you would want the body diode to be reverse-biased in the off state.  Then the channel gets enhanced to allow current to flow in the on state.  Depending on Vth, your FET is likely well on and conducting in the circuit above.

Comment: If you put the MOSFET the other way around then your LED would always be on, irrespective of what you did with the MOSFET's gate pin, because the body diode would always conduct.